# how to sum elements of a model and return the total in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to Django and after spending a lot of time on this (and still being stuck) I thought to ask for some expert help!

In this small project, what I'm trying to achieve is a webpage that returns the total amount in GBP of a user's investments (only cash investments for now). I have created some python scripts to get the FX rates.

I'm trying to sum up all the amounts in GBP however I'm stuck! I don't know whether I should do this in the model (Cash) or in the view and how to then show it in the template(cash_list.html).

Your help would be really appreciated.

**Workings below**

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class fx_table(models.Model):
    eur_to_gbp_pair = 'EUR/GBP'
    aud_to_gbp_pair = 'AUD/GBP'
    usd_to_gbp_pair = 'AUD/USD'

    eur_to_gbp = models.FloatField(default=0)
    aud_to_gbp = models.FloatField(default=0)
    usd_to_gbp = models.FloatField(default=0)

    date_time = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True,default='')

class Cash(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from fx_rates_app.models import Cash
from fx_rates_app.models import Shares


class NewUserFormCash(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Cash
        fields = '__all__' #You want to be able to change all the fields


class NewUserFormShares(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Shares
        fields = '__all__'
```

Python script

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','fx_rates_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()


from fx_rates_app.models import fx_table

import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
os.environ["ALPHAVANTAGE_API_KEY"] = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
fx_gbp_to_eur = web.DataReader("GBP/EUR","av-forex")
eur = float(fx_gbp_to_eur[4:5].values[0][0])

fx_gbp_to_aud = web.DataReader("GBP/AUD","av-forex")
aud = float(fx_gbp_to_aud[4:5].values[0][0])


fx_gbp_to_usd = web.DataReader("GBP/USD","av-forex")
usd = float(fx_gbp_to_usd[4:5].values[0][0])

from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

webpg1 = fx_table.objects.get_or_create(eur_to_gbp=eur,aud_to_gbp=aud,usd_to_gbp=usd,date_time=dt_string)[0]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from fx_rates_app.models import fx_table
from fx_rates_app.forms import NewUserFormCash,NewUserFormShares
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView
from django.urls import reverse
from fx_rates_app import forms
from fx_rates_app.models import Cash, Shares,fx_table
import datetime

class CashListView(ListView):
    model = Cash
    context_object_name = 'cash_details'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CashListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'fx_list': fx_table.objects.all(),
            'insert': datetime.datetime.now(),
        })
        return context

class SharesListView(ListView):
    model = Shares
    context_object_name = 'shares_details'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SharesListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'fx_list': fx_table.objects.all(),
        })
        return context

def Cash(request):

    form_cash = NewUserFormCash()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_cash = NewUserFormCash(request.POST) 

        if form_cash.is_valid():
            form_cash.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

        else:
            print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

    return render(request,'fx_rates_app/cash_positions.html',{'form':form_cash})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from fx_rates_app import views
from fx_rates_app.views import CashListView,SharesListView,FxListView

app_name = 'fx_rates_app'


urlpatterns = [
    path('fx/',FxListView.as_view(), name='fx'),
    path('cash_positions/',views.Cash,name='cash_positions'),
    path('shares/',views.Shares,name='shares'),
    path('cash_list/',CashListView.as_view(), name='cash_list'),
    path('shares_list/',SharesListView.as_view(), name='shares_list'),

]
```

cash_list.html

```
{% extends 'fx_rates_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
{% load mathfilters %}


<div class="container">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Reference</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Currency</th>
    <th>Equivalent in GBP</th>
  </thead>

  {% for item in cash_details %}
  {% for ele in fx_list %}

  <tr>
    <td> {{ item.reference }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.amount|floatformat:0|intcomma }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.currency }} </td>

        {% if item.currency == "AUD" %}
        <td>{{ item.amount|div:ele.aud_to_gbp|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>

        {% elif item.currency == "EUR" %}
        <td>{{ item.amount|div:ele.eur_to_gbp|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>

        {% elif item.currency == "USD" %}
        <td>{{ item.amount|div:ele.usd_to_gbp|floatformat:0|intcomma }}</td>

        {% else %}
        <td> {{ item.amount|floatformat:0|intcomma }} </td>

        {% endif %}

  </tr>

  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}


<tr>
  <td> Total </td>
  <td>  </td>
  <td>  </td>
  <td> Total in GBP here</td>
</tr>



  {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try like this in view:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, When, Case, FloatField, Value, F

class CashListView(ListView):
    model = Cash
    context_object_name = 'cash_details'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CashListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        latest_fx = fx_table.objects.last()
        queryset = context['cash_details'].annotate(amount_in_gbp=Case(
                When(currency="AUD", then=F('amount')/latest_fx.aud_to_gbp),
                When(currency="USD", then=F('amount')/latest_fx.usd_to_gbp),
                When(currency="EUR", then=F('amount')/latest_fx.eur_to_gbp),
                default=F('amount'),
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )
        context['cash_details'] = queryset
        context['total_in_gbp'] = queryset.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount_in_gbp'))['sum']
        return context

# template
{% for item in cash_details %}

  <tr>
    <td> {{ item.reference }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.amount|floatformat:0|intcomma }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.currency }} </td>
    <td> {{ item.amount_in_gbp|floatformat:0|intcomma }} </td>
  </tr>

{% endfor %}

Total: {{ total_in_gbp }}
```

I am using [Conditional Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/) to sum up all the values per currency.

Comment: Thanks for your help ruddra. I tried the code however I get the following error:                  
views.py in get_context_data, line 29                                                                                  'dict' object is not callable. Do you know what it could be? Also, where did you use group by?

Comment: I used group by in `cash_sum`. Also I fixed the error(sorry about that). please see the updated answer

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. I don't get any error now but the html doesn't show anything. Shouldn't I just replace my get_context_data with your function?

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought however when I replace the code and refresh the server all the content of the table in the html disappear.

Comment: It looks like that {% for item in cash_details %} it's no longer working and also I think I need to replace fx_list with latest_fx in the html

Comment: Ah, yep. If you are okay showing GBP value based on only the latest_fx. In that case, you need to send via context as well

Comment: Sorry to be a pain! How can I do that? I tried to change fx_list to latest_fx but it doesn't work. Also, the 'amount' and 'currency' columns (which should get data from cash_details' are empty. Thanks in advance

Comment: Great! Thanks very much for all your help. It works perfectly.